# SSH-Can only connect once without disconnecting wifi

Tags: ssh, connection

I have a question about SSH or network problems. Let me explain. Normally when I try to connect to a machine with SSH, entering it's password and other stuff it lets me connect normally. However, when I try to connect to that same adress again with the same credentials I entered it gives me a permission denied error. If I disconnect wifi and try to make a connection again it works. The problem here is **Why do I have to disconnect to do a SSH every time?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

**tmux** it maintains your ssh connection

Install tmux:

- sudo apt update
- sudo apt-get install tmux
- tmux

Please ref:
https://www.howtogeek.com/671422/how-to-use-tmux-on-linux-and-why-its-better-than-screen/

Comment: That wasn't the answer I was looking for. I think it has something do with my firewall. But since you have mentioned tmux is there an alternative version of it for windows perhaps?